# Understanding the basics of spacecraft thermal control systems

Tags: thermal, heat, radiators, liquid-cooled

I have a broad understanding that in spacecraft cooling systems where a circulating liquid is used, a first coolant usually runs through the spacecraft and collects heat and then passes through a heat exchanger with a second loop of liquid that takes it to the radiator.

Is my understanding that two-loop systems are used flawed, or basically correct?

An example diagram showing this would be helpful as well.

Comment: "A" diagram? There are hundreds if not thousands of different designs. Pick a spacecraft! If you pick the shuttle, I will fix you right up with diagrams. Right now this is too broad.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've modified the wording to emphasize the OPs interest in the two-loop aspect. and moved the request for a diagram from the beginning to the end.

Comment: It varies wildly. Can include passive conduction/radiation, heat pipes, pumped loops, double pumped loops, etc. Can also include heat-pumped systems.